# My Javascript hotkey combination is not changing to my new code

Tags: javascript, php

I have a web app that uses the following JavaScript to set up hot keys,

```
function readKeys(e) {
    if (e.key == 'n' && e.ctrlKey == true && e.altKey == true) {
        some stuff
    }
    if (e.key == 'd' && e.ctrlKey == true && e.altKey == true) {
        some other stuff
    }
}
```

In Linux,  the `ctrl+alt+d` combination is a system hotkey, so I changed my code to this:

```
function readKeys(e) {
    if (e.key == 'n' && e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        some stuff
    }
    if (e.key == 'd' && e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        some other stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is that the old hot key still works and the new one does not.

So this is what I have done:
 1. I cleared the browser's cache: no luck

2. I added this to my php file:

   header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
   header("Progma: no-cache");
   header("Expires: 0");
   session_cache_limiter('nocache');
   session_start();

still no luck.

3. I added a version to my JavaScript call

   src='../javascript/note.js?version=1.0.1'

no luck.

4. I renamed my JavaScript file: no luck
5. I downloaded Chrome and tried it out there, and it still ran the old code, so it clearly is not a browser caching issue.
6. So then: I went into my `php.ini` file and set `opcache.enable=0` and `opcache.enable_cli=0` and `opcache.revalidate_freq=0`. I then restarted the Apache server, no luck.
7. I went into `httpd.conf` and commented out `include conf/pagespeed.conf` and `include conf/pagespeedlibraries.conf` and restarted the server: same problem.

When I view "web source" on Firefox, I see the correct code, but it still runs the old code instead. This same problem exist in my localhost and online.

I am using the **Bitnami LAMP stack** locally.

Insanity and despair are racing to see which will get me first.
What am I missing?

Comment: Assuming `e` is a `KeyboardEvent`, it’s `e.altKey`, not `e.altkey`. `e.altkey` will always be `undefined` and `e.altkey == true` will always be `false`.

Comment: @Xufox Yes, `e` is a `KeyboardEvent`. I mis-typed my code in my question and I corrected it. The code in my project was correct as it worked fine and still works, which it shouldn't because I replaced it.